# How to reindex Elasticsearch data from old version to new version

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, reindex

I am new to Elasticsearch and I want to know  How to reindex Elasticsearch data from old version  to new version,

Use case:
I have old index created in version 5 named as data_1 and I want to get it re indexed in version 6

to display i can run below
**curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'**

to get mapping I can run below
**curl -GET http://localhost:9200/data_1/_mapping?pretty**

now question is how to create new index with same old mapping, I referred this link https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/6-steps-to-reindex-elasticsearch-data/  & https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/docs-reindex.html

but its not explaining how to add same mapping in new index which we create to re index old one.

can someone help me here I am new to ES.

Regards,
Samurai

Comment: the only real structural difference between the versions of ES is that they depreciated the ability to have multiple types in an single index, if you are using that feature then you will need to split the index by type into several indexes, before it will work in a newer version of ES

Comment: the links you have provided are for changing the mapping on the same server not for migrating from an old version to a new version or transfering from one server to another this is probably a better fit https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrating-data.html